# How to run ordered JUnit5 tests in parallel mode

Tags: java, selenium, junit5

I have a need to run dependent tests (not unit, but long UI-scenarios with selenium). There are reasons related to the environment, because of which I have to prepare a "random" state, and use this state in other tests. To do this, I perform a series of actions, after which I get a link, save it to a static String variable in a method annotated as @Order (1). After that, in methods annotated by @Order (2 and more), the link stored in the static String variable is available

Usually the order is random, but if you follow the [manual](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order), then in one thread everything works great.

The number of tests is quite large, so it seemed logical to run them in parallel. It's [no problem](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) for 5.3 and newer version. I use "Configuration parameters to execute top-level classes in parallel but methods in same thread". For ordinary test classes it works like that.
And now the problem. Just add the @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT), how the order stops working. Because of this, instead of link in a static variable, I get null.
Is it possible to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Prose description of code is hard to understand. Consider to add a minimal code example that reveals the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, the description seemed pretty transparent to me. Here is the simple of test class:
`
`

Comment: `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
//both on-off does not work:
//@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TariffNewNonOfficialTest extends SetupEnv implements HelpMeth {
    private static String testUrl;
    @Order(1)
    @Test
    void firstTest() {
 /*someActons*/
 testUrl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
    }`
Order(2) use testUrl.  Properties set  to execute top-level classes in parallel but methods in same thread.

Comment: Formatted code cannot correctly be displayed in comments. I suggest you update the question and put it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty noob mistake. 
It turned out to be enough to add annotation @Execution(ExecutionMode.SAME_THREAD) to each method that should be executed in the same thread as the parent.

It's not entirely clear what the settings do in junit-platform.properties. 
But perhaps I wishful thinking by reading the manual.
It took half a day to understand this (((